# Association file in terminal server for all users

Tags: file, associations, windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-server

I am trying to associate .hod files to IBM i Access Client Solution.
IBM site says to use "open with" Windows menu, but in terminal server 2008 R2 if an user associates .hod file to that program, on the next logon (maybe for redirecting or policy reasones) it becomes an unidentifyed file.
Is there a way to fix that extension with that program even if it is only an executable file without installation? And for all users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found that the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE -> CLASSES contains the same registry Keys as HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> SOFTWARE -> CLASSES.
I have associated my .hod file with i Access Client Solution and copied the Keys from HKCU to HKLM.
Now it works for all users and persists after restart.